# Extracted XML content from postgres not recognized in R

Tags: xml, r, postgresql

I use a substring query in PostGresql to generate the following output.

I used this in the dbGetQuery in R studio:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT substring(response from 11 for       position('</ConsumerEnquiry>'     in response) + 8)  FROM za.scoring_result where id in (334)")
```

The Output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ConsumerEnquiry>
 <Session>
  <User_ID>ROCK1</User_ID>
  <FullName>ROCK1</FullName>
  <GroupName>014828</GroupName>
  <Subscriber_ID>14828</Subscriber_ID>
  <Group_ID>014828</Group_ID>
  <RequestType>XML2</RequestType>
  <Environment>PRODUCTION</Environment>
  <Version>1.0.0</Version>
 </Session>
</ConsumerEnquiry>
```

When I try:

```
file2 = xmlParse("SA_Data_1")
```

I get an error:

Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'SA_Data_1'

Can someone help me? My first post here.. :)

Comment: could you post here the output of `dput(SA_Data_1)`

Comment: Its trying to parse the string "SA_Data_1" which obviously isn't XML data...

Comment: aah I saw what I wanted to see! completely overlooked the quotes there

Comment: @Ossan.. Firstly thanks a lot for trying to help.. I really appreciate it.. Here is the output:

Comment: structure(list(substring = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<ConsumerEnquiry>\n<Session>\n<User_ID>ROCKLEND1</User_ID>\n<FullName>ROCKLEND1</FullName>\n<GroupName>014828</GroupName>\n<Subscriber_ID>14828</Subscriber_ID>\n<Group_ID>014828</Group_ID>\n<RequestType>XML2</RequestType>\n<Environment>PRODUCTION</Environment>\n<Version>1.0.0</Version>\n</Session></ConsumerEnquiry>\n"),.Names = "substring", row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the output. I'm guessing you really mean to do:

```
SA_Data_1 = dbGetQuery(con,
   "SELECT substring(response from 11 for  position('</ConsumerEnquiry>' in response) + 8)  
    FROM za.scoring_result where id in (334)")
```

assuming this returns the XML as a character string, then you can do

```
SA_parsed = xmlParse(SA_Data_1$substring)
```

to get a parsed version of the XML. Then you can extract bits from it using the rest of the XML package.

```
file2 = xmlParse("SA_Data_1")
```

fails because its interpreting "SA_Data_1" as a piece of XML, which it isn't.

Comment: Hi Spacedman.. Thanks for your reply.. this doesnt help.. However if I save the file as a '.xml' file and then import it into R, I am able to perform all operations.. I really dont understand why the xmlParse is not working inside R..

Comment: How do you mean "does not help"? Does `SA_parsed = xmlParse(SA_Data_1)` not work? Does it error message? What error message?

Comment: Error in file.exists(file) : invalid 'file' argument

Comment: Try also: `SA_parsed = xmlParse(SA_Data_1[[1]])` because it looks like your text is the first element of a list, given the output of `dput` in your comment (which you should have put in the question).

Comment: Hi Spacedman.. Thanks a million.. that works actually.. I am sorry I should have mentioned that I am newbie to R.. and I do not even know what dput is.. Would it be possible to explain what text I have in the data?

Comment: The return from `dbGetQuery` is a "data frame", and actually you should probably use `SA_Data_1$substring` to get the text rather than `[[1]]`.

Comment: Yes you are right.. That helps a lot.. Thanks everyone.. :) Cheers,Siva